# No puedo instalar luna librería de codeblocks

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

En este caso es criterion https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion
he linkeado la librería pero me sale este error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo el por que si he seguido todos los pasos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tú dices *he linkeado la librería*, seria genial que muestres como lo has enlazado.

Comment: Ya he subido las imagenes